# Restart Nginx through a PHP Script

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm currently working to make a WordPress plugin of mine compatible with nginx. This plugin requires access to a `.conf` file in the `wp-content/uploads` directory, so that it can add in the required rules. Currently, it updates an `.htaccess` file in the same directory, and the changes take effect immediately without intervention. Because nginx requires `service nginx reload` to allow configuration changes to take effect, I am looking for a way to do that in my script. I'm not sure that even `exec()` would work for this, as `service nginx reload` is required to be run as root or using sudo. I've searched far and wide on StackExchange, Google, and everywhere else that I know of, and I can't even find a starting place.

Comment: Security disaster right there. Do not do this. Even if you manage to securely allow the PHP app to restart Nginx (by editing the sudoers file and only allowing that one restart command), it still opens up a DoS vulnerability as any malicious PHP script is now able to DoS the server by continuously making Nginx reload.

Comment: @AndréDaniel, Of course, I don't disagree with you; I don't want any user related to the web server to be able to execute commands as sudo. But, my goal was to find a "good" way to accomplish this that didn't offer up a huge security vulnerability (like `exec()`, allowing the `www-data` user to have sudo access, etc.). My point in mentioning that was there is no way to even `exec()` that command, because it is required to run as sudo/root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Security wise, it would be a VERY bad thing to give the user that runs the web server sudo/root access.  Rather, you could use a semaphore file and have a cron job run by root that runs every 5 minutes (or higher frequency if required) that looks for the presence of this file.  If present, it issues the `service nginx reload` command and deletes the file.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree that giving sudo access to the `www-data` user would be crazy stupid. This is a good start. I think that the problem that would occur with this would be related to distributed server environments. If a user is running multiple servers with the same `wp-content/uploads` folder source, only one server would get reloaded. Maybe there is a better way to watch for the file to update, and then trigger a `service nginx reload`.

Answer (score 2):

### My Suggestion

Overall I think the best solution would be to have your plugin create specific instructions for the user to edit any Nginx config manually and then reload Nginx themselves.

I believe this because giving PHP the ability to run a command that usually requires sudo requires opening up a large security hole.

On top of that, the methods that a user would have to do in order to allow PHP to run the `service nginx reload` command is not something you can accomplish in PHP alone, and may be equally, if not more, complex than having them update Nginx config and reloading themselves. The user needs to do extra work regardless!

### If you *really* want to do this:

If you still choose to go down this course of action, I suggest having users of the plugin edit the server's `/etc/sudoers` file, which can allow user `www-data` (or any other user) to run that one specific command using sudo without requiring a password. This also means that the user (perhaps www-data) would NOT have permission to run any other command, which is at least a bit more secure.

> Use the `sudo visudo` command to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file. Don't edit it directly.

Here's the line to add to that file for user `www-data`:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/service nginx reload
```

[Here's an example of allowing a user (group)](https://serversforhackers.com/video/enhancing-envoy-deployment) to run similar commands, with some more explanation. Here's [more on Sudoers and how /etc/sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) works.

Lastly, note that user `www-data` is specific to installing Nginx on Debian/Ubuntu Linux distributions. Other very common distributions (centos, redhat, fedora, arch, etc etc etc) may not be running Nginx/PHP-FPM as user `www-data` unless the sysadmin creates those users manually.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want any user related to the web server to be able to execute commands as sudo. I think there is the ability to incorporate user notification, as well as @dbinns66's solution below, to say, either you can reload this yourself every time you make a change, or you can use this program, script, etc. to monitor the file and restart nginx when it changes.

Comment: I really disagree with the "If you really want to do this part".  I agree with the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Bad idea. Don't do it.

**Long answer:** What you try do to cannot be compared with editing a `.htaccess` file simply because it does not work the same way.  `.htaccess` files are made to be edited and reloaded on the fly and can be created and accessed almost in every directory inside your public directory.

That is not the case for Nginx configurations.  Configuration files are made to be loaded when Nginx starts or manually when needed.  Their location is related to the configuration defined by the administrator.

Even if you knew where the file was, it could be impossible for you to update it or write in that specific directory.

More than that, you'll have to figure out what user *can* write and read where the configuration files are located.

In the end, there are so many thing that can go wrong. In my humble opinion, the idea is really bad.

What most plugins do is display the Nginx configuration that should be included so the website administrator can copy and paste it.  Or, they create a `.conf` file that the website administrator must copy somewhere before restarting Nginx.

What you try to achieve is doable. It can be coded.  Don't get me wrong.  **BUT** your plugin will become about handling every specificty of every Nginx configuration there is out there.  You really don't want that.

As you don't know every configuration (and honestly, you don't want to know), I'd suggest you focus on developing a great plugin and offering the right Nginx configuration via the plugin.  The last part (where the website administrator copies it to the right location and reloads the configuration) is his job.

The other answers I read in that question suggest ways of "trying" to achieve what you are asking.  I think they will create more problems than they'll help.  By changing permissions and running crons, it may work.  But you'll also open the door to security vulnerabilities as your `www-data` user or website user owner will now be considered as `root` and could run things that should not be run.  I would not advise you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You must add correct permissions to account www-data which is used to execute commands on Linux webservers. You see which account is executing script with PHP by using `<?php echo exec("whoami"); ?>`

Comment: How would adding the correct permissions to the account make a difference? I know that PHP-FPM executes files as the www-data user and has the proper permissions required to run my application, but that doesn't really solve my problem of how to get the server to reload the nginx configuration.

Comment: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com
chmod 775 /var/www with those commands if I remember. I had similar issue with "youtube-dl" you should locate the webserver file that it uses to restart it and modify variable of those commands for them. There should be the files as binary or something. http://superuser.com/questions/646062/granting-write-permissions-to-www-data-group or create a batch file for it and run it.